# Do authors generally use fully connected layer instead of affine transformation?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology

We generally encounter the following statement several times

> The input vector is first fed into a **fully connected layer**......

Since linear activation functions, such as identity function, can so considered as an activation functions, a fully connected layer can be considered just as an Affine transformation if the fully connected layer uses linear activation function.

So, in theory, a fully connected layer can refer to the following

1. Just an affine transformation
2. Affine transformation followed by a nonlinear activation function

Do authors generally choose to use "fully connected layer" for case 2 only or for both cases 1 and 2?

Comment: Affine transformations have this property that multiple affine transformations are equivalent to one affine transformation, so you gain nothing by stacking such layers.

Comment: @user253751 consider a single one.

Comment: According to my experience, it refers to the 2nd case. When you're talking of neural networks, it's implicitly assumed you use a non-linear activation function at the end of each layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, typically, a fully connected layer is an affine transformation, which can or not be followed by a non-linear activation function, but, in many (if not most) cases, it's followed by a non-linearity, such as ReLU, sigmoid, or tanh ([an exception is when you do regression](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/31722/2444)), which is what makes the neural network be able to [approximate non-linear/complicated functions](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/13319/2444).